# "For all $\epsilon>0$, if $a+\epsilon>b$, then $a>b$" vs "If, for all $\epsilon>0$, $a+\epsilon>b$, then $a>b$".

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

[Peter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/88804/peter) [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/508464):

> If $a + \epsilon > b$ for each $\epsilon > 0$, can we conclude that $a > b$?

[Micah](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/30836/micah) [commented](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508464/for-every-epsilon-0-if-a-epsilon-b-can-we-conclude-ab#comment1090939_508464)

> Be careful: **[$\Large{1.}$]** "for every $ϵ>0$, if $a+ϵ>b$, then $a>b$" is a different statement than
> **[$\Large{2.}$]** "if, for every $ϵ>0, a+ϵ>b$, then $a>b$."
> One of them is a lot closer to being true than the other.

[Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12042/brian-m-scott) [expounded on why conditional statement #1 is false](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/508468). But my difficulty is grislier! As English isn't my first language, I can't even distinguish between the two conditionals, which mean the same to me! What's the simplest way to distinguish between them?

As both share the same apodosis ("then $a> b$"), I only pay attention to the protasis. I spot only one difference: the placement of $\color{limegreen}{\text{"if"}}$. The protasis of 1 is

> for every $ϵ>0, \color{limegreen}{\text{if }} a+ϵ>b$

The protasis of 2 is

> $\color{limegreen}{\text{if}}$, for every $ϵ>0, a+ϵ>b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In statement 2's protasis, there is actually an if-then statement. It is "if 'if $\epsilon > 0$, then $a+\epsilon > b$'".

This is clunky to say in plain English, so people use the "for every" quantifier instead.

**So statement 2 actually says:**

"if

> 'if $\epsilon > 0$, then $a+\epsilon > b$'

,

then $a>b$".

**On the other hand, statement 1 is:**

"if $\epsilon > 0$, then

> 'if $a+\epsilon > b$, then $a>b$'

."

**So which one is true?**

Looking at it this way, it is clear that statement 2 is not true (because try letting $a=b=1$), but in some sense "close to being true", because changing the conclusion to $a\ge b$ makes it true.

However, statement 1 is "nowhere near being true", because try letting $\epsilon = 10$ and $a=1,b=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since your issue is a linguistic one, I'll write down the two statements in logical notation. Pay close attention to the placement of the brackets.

**Statement 1:**
$$ (\forall a \in \mathbb R)\bigg[(\forall b \in \mathbb R)\bigg[(\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R^+) \bigg[ (a + \epsilon > b) \implies (a > b) \bigg]\bigg]\bigg]$$

**Statement 2:**
$$ (\forall a \in \mathbb R)\bigg[(\forall b \in \mathbb R)\bigg[(\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R^+) \bigg[ (a + \epsilon > b)  \bigg] \implies  (a > b)\bigg]\bigg]$$

Comment: Thanks. I see merely one difference: the placement of ]. Statement 1 ends with 3 ]'s. Statement 2 ends with 2 ]'s, because you placed one ] before $\Longrightarrow$. But how does this answer my question? I still befuddled!

Comment: @user1147844 I thought your question is about how to translate the English sentences into logical statements?

Comment: Yes, that's the first part. But I want to distinguish, and intuit, these logical statements too!